# VB.NET - integrate Win7 taskbar progress without the external DLLs?

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, taskbar, progress

Hey trying to make a fancy little app here in VB.NET framework 4.
I've seen several programs which utilise windows 7's taskbar progressbar, but they have it embedded in the application
when i googled and attempted to do this, my program had to lug around 3 extra dlls when its supposed to be a single executable, and highly portable.
how can i gain access to the taskbar progressbar without having to drag about these resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the Windows API. The [Windows API Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24081665/87698) includes C# code that shows how these Windows API functions (including the Windows 7 taskbar progress icon) are accessed through .NET.

Yes, usually you'd compile this API pack into a DLL and distribute it with your project, but since the source code is available and the license seems to be quite permissive (please double-check yourself, I'm not a lawyer), you could translate the relevant parts of the code to VB (there are plenty of tools available for that online) and include it in your project. That way, you still have your single EXE file without external dependencies.

Comment: Why thank you, I had downloaded this once before but I never thought to actually copy the necessary code rather than lug around the whole API dll with me.
Much appreciated!

Comment: Now Windows API Code Pack does not exists because Microsoft Archive Gallery is no longer available, if you don't modify the answer, probably you will get downvoted

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales: Feel free to update the link to its current URL.

Comment: @Heinzi There's not a current URL because some of the projects are translated to MSDN, but Windows API Code Pack is removed permanently

Comment: @CodigosTutoriales: I already did. :-) Try the link in the question.