# Frame rate of video file in universal windows platform

Tags: c#, video, metadata, mediaelement, win-universal-app

How can I access **frame rate of video file** in Windows 10 application?

[image]

I tried external libraries like [MediaInfoNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaInfoNet), or [taglib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/) for reading metadata, but these are not compactible with UWP (at least nuget is telling me this).
Also MediaElement seems pretty evolved, but has no FPS property.

Is there any option?

Comment: The value you highlighted is extracted by MPEG-4 [shell property handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728871) through COM and Media Foundation API underneath. The keyword is [`PKEY_Video_FrameRate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862).

Comment: @Roman R : If I understand well, I need windows api code pack?? It is retired http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it , but can be downloaded for example through nuget. It is same problem: it is not compatible with UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all it is easy.

```
 List<string> encodingPropertiesToRetrieve = new List<string>();
 encodingPropertiesToRetrieve.Add("System.Video.FrameRate");
 IDictionary<string, object> encodingProperties = await file.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(encodingPropertiesToRetrieve);
 uint frameRateX1000 = (uint)encodingProperties["System.Video.FrameRate"];
```

Where 
***file***
is  ***Windows.Storage.StorageFile***

FrameRate is multiply by 1000.

More info about [Metadata Properties for Media Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862).