# MsgBox with details window

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for Message box control which could give me possibility also to have details windows inside. This is because sometime user doesn't want to see error message, therefore i could place additional detailed message in details section and user can decide whether to open it and read or just read main message. I know its not possible within available `MsgBox` but do you know maybe some custom control i could use? I know i could use `PropertyGrid` but i am not sure if its secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Task Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471(v=vs.85).aspx). It's part of the [Windows API Code Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it).

[image: Example Task Dialog]

Comment: yes that nice, the problem is when i am testing it the icon is not showing up, everything else working.

Comment: I realize this is old, but is there an implementation of this that contains a textbox control, similar to the exception dialog that contains the stack trace from the JIT debugger? I'm working on rolling my own dialog like this to display details (collapsed unless the user clicks a Show Details button) for certain, very specific events in my application, but I'd be just as happy if I didn't have to reinvent something that's already out there.