# Without opening, how can I read OpenXML document properties of password protected files programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel

I have an application which generates passwords for .xlsx files algorithmically based on custom document properties. Persistence of the properties is ensured by setting the openxmlencryptproperty key to false. As such, the file content is password protected, but the properties are visible (via explorer).

The intended functionality is that the password is recalculated from the properties before attempting to open the workbook. Unfortunately, the only methods I can find to get at these properties involve opening the workbook (either via System.IO.Packaging or OpenXml.Packaging).

Clearly explorer is able to read these properties without actually opening the file. How can I replicate this behaviour in C#? (perhaps invoking an instance of explorer?).

Comment: I'm pretty sure Explorer has an [Metadata handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761474(v=vs.85).aspx) that reads the file. There is no magic.

Answer (score 1):

After various attempts to leverage the properties using the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` API, the only way I was able to get to *custom* properties was via the `StructuredStorage` API, as demonstrated in the snippet provided in the second part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35548859/1065973) accepted answer to a similar question.