# How to read Custom file attributes in Windows using Java

Tags: java

When right clicking on the particular file and select Properties in Windows, I get the following view:

[image]

How can I access those properties (Name, Value, Type) using Java as shown in the picture above?

I have tried [BasicFileAttributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) and [UserDefinedFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html) with no luck. It seems I can't access those attributes. Anyone has any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Looks nontrivial. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35451540/22270964) will help you to find a solution. Good luck!

Comment: I have an idea how to get this info. Could you provide a file itself? I can't find similar on my own.

Comment: @MaksimEliseev this seems to be a solution for c#, not java

Comment: @OlegCherednik https://filetransfer.io/manage-package/jEETstE0

Comment: @MaVRoSCy It gives me 404

Comment: IIRC, they are stored in a Alternate Data Stream. You should be able to open that as a normal file and read it. That said, this "Custom" tab is not a standard feature of Windows, so it is possible that this is a custom view specifically for this file-type, and it has a driver that reads or writes this to the file itself.

Comment: @OlegCherednik what about this https://easyupload.io/59bfvt ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on really what these attributes are. I'm guessing they are in an NTFS ADS. Try something like the following:

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class NtfsStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path file = Path.of(args[0]);
        UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
        for (String name : view.list()) {
            ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(view.size(name));
            view.read(name, buf);
            buf.flip();
            String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf).toString();
            System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried that as already pointed out in the question and sadly it doesnt work...

Comment: Using UserDefinedFileAttributeView , i am able to add an attribute and read it, but cannot read the rest of the attributes already present in the file as shown in the picture

Comment: Well I *did* say it depends on the type of attributes ;) What type of file is that .ac file?

Comment: https://documentation.caseware.com/2022/WorkingPapers/en/Content/Engagements/File-Preparation/Create-Files/File-Extension-Index.htm

Comment: OK. Now it might help if you can get that link working that you posted

Comment: this should work https://easyupload.io/59bfvt

Comment: Downloaded fine this one

Comment: I think what you're looking at there might be an Explorer tab provided essentially by Caseware, giving you a view of info contained in one of its proprietary format files. Crude reverse engineering provided by `strings -e l -t x MetaDataExample2010.ac`