How to retrieve a list of all available file properties for all file types
I wish to retrieve a list of ALL available file properties (i.e. the same list that you get when you click More in Explorer).
Currently, I can get the desired results by running Nirsoft's PropertySystemView tool with its /AllProperties argument and then parsing its output to include properties that have a non-blank Display Name and where the Viewable value is Yes.
However, I wish to eliminate the use of PropertySystemView.exe and retrieve the property list directly in my own C# code. I have found many code examples for retrieving the properties for an individual file, but I have not found anything that shows how to retrieve all properties. Therefore, I have no code to show in my question.
This question is NOT a duplicate of this question. As you can see there, I asked Simon Mourier in the comments about retrieving ALL properties and he said that code would NOT do it and I should ask a new question.

I think the question was extensively answered by Simon Mourier in the linked question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451540/extracting-windows-file-properties-custom-properties-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1. Check it out ;)

@borealis-c I guess you did not see that I asked Simon Mourier in the comments there about retrieving ALL properties and he said that code would NOT do it and I should ask a new question.

I guess you should have mentioned that comment in this question so as to avoid exactly this kind of exchange. This is what is meant by the section titled "Search, and research" in [ask].

@HereticMonkey I thought I was clear by emphasizing ALL properties and that I found many code examples for retrieving the properties for an individual file, but I will take your advice and add additional clarification. And thanks for fixing my grammatical error.

The root API you want to use is this PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-psenumeratepropertydescriptions) However it's quite a work in C# since you have to use quite a lot of interop (there are lots of properties & methods). It's easier using this interop-generator project https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32 but requires .NET5+ and unsafe code. Is that would be ok, or what exactly do you need?

Here is a sample .NET 8 code that for example dumps all properties key, canonical name and display name https://pastebin.com/raw/qgGPDYrX

@SimonMourier Yes, that's it! Thank you! To get the list reduced to the the items that I need, I also had to filter on ISVIEWABLE. I did that with the addition of pd.GetTypeFlags(PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS.PDTF_ISVIEWABLE, out var v); and bool isViewable = v == PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS.PDTF_ISVIEWABLE;. If you post an answer with your code, I'll mark it as the answer.

@SimonMourier My current program uses .Net 4.8 and runs on Windows 7 and above. I may change to .Net 8 (and restrict it to Win 10 and 11) but if I want to stick with 4.8, could this dump code be adapted to .Net 4.8?

To get all properties, you must use the PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions function
Here is a .NET Framework version which redefines (partially) some interfaces and types you need:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions(PROPDESC_ENUMFILTER.PDEF_ALL, typeof(IPropertyDescriptionList).GUID, out var list);
        for (var i = 0; i < list.GetCount(); i++)
        {
            var pd = list.GetAt(i, typeof(IPropertyDescription).GUID);

            var pk = pd.GetPropertyKey();
            Console.WriteLine($"Property Key   : {pk.fmtid:B} {pk.pid}");

            pd.GetCanonicalName(out var name);
            Console.WriteLine($"Canonical Name : {Marshal.PtrToStringUni(name)}");
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(name);

            pd.GetDisplayName(out name);
            if (name != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Display Name   : {Marshal.PtrToStringUni(name)}");
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(name);
            }

            var viewable = pd.GetTypeFlags(PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS.PDTF_ISVIEWABLE) == PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS.PDTF_ISVIEWABLE;
            Console.WriteLine($"Viewable       : {viewable}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public struct PROPERTYKEY
    {
        public Guid fmtid;
        public int pid;
    }

    public enum PROPDESC_ENUMFILTER
    {
        PDEF_ALL = 0,
        PDEF_SYSTEM = 1,
        PDEF_NONSYSTEM = 2,
        PDEF_VIEWABLE = 3,
        PDEF_QUERYABLE = 4,
        PDEF_INFULLTEXTQUERY = 5,
        PDEF_COLUMN = 6,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS
    {
        PDTF_DEFAULT = 0,
        PDTF_MULTIPLEVALUES = 0x1,
        PDTF_ISINNATE = 0x2,
        PDTF_ISGROUP = 0x4,
        PDTF_CANGROUPBY = 0x8,
        PDTF_CANSTACKBY = 0x10,
        PDTF_ISTREEPROPERTY = 0x20,
        PDTF_INCLUDEINFULLTEXTQUERY = 0x40,
        PDTF_ISVIEWABLE = 0x80,
        PDTF_ISQUERYABLE = 0x100,
        PDTF_CANBEPURGED = 0x200,
        PDTF_SEARCHRAWVALUE = 0x400,
        PDTF_DONTCOERCEEMPTYSTRINGS = 0x800,
        PDTF_ALWAYSINSUPPLEMENTALSTORE = 0x1000,
        PDTF_ISSYSTEMPROPERTY = unchecked((int)0x80000000),
        PDTF_MASK_ALL = unchecked((int)0x80001fff),
    }

    [DllImport("propsys")]
    public static extern int PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions(PROPDESC_ENUMFILTER filterOn, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IPropertyDescriptionList ppv);

    [ComImport, Guid("1F9FC1D0-C39B-4B26-817F-011967D3440E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPropertyDescriptionList
    {
        int GetCount();
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
        IPropertyDescription GetAt(int iElem, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid);
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("6F79D558-3E96-4549-A1D1-7D75D2288814"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IPropertyDescription
    {
        PROPERTYKEY GetPropertyKey();
        [PreserveSig] int GetCanonicalName(out IntPtr name);
        int GetPropertyType();
        [PreserveSig] int GetDisplayName(out IntPtr name);
        [PreserveSig] int GetEditInvitation(out IntPtr name);
        PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS GetTypeFlags(PROPDESC_TYPE_FLAGS mask);
        // following methods are undefined in this code since we don't need it
    }
}

If you use .NET Core 5+ you can benefit from the CsWin32 project which will define all needed interop for you. Note using this requires to declare your code unsafe somehow. Introp code is also auto-generated so using it is not strictly equivalent (uint vs int, etc.)
csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="NativeMethods.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="NativeMethods.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32" Version="0.3.106">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

NativeMethods.txt:
IPropertyDescription
IPropertyDescriptionList
PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions

Program.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using Windows.Win32;
using Windows.Win32.UI.Shell.PropertiesSystem;

[assembly: SupportedOSPlatform("windows6.0.6000")]

namespace DumpShellProps;

internal class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main()
    {
        PInvoke.PSEnumeratePropertyDescriptions(PROPDESC_ENUMFILTER.PDEF_ALL, typeof(IPropertyDescriptionList).GUID, out var ppv).ThrowOnFailure();
        var list = (IPropertyDescriptionList)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown((nint)ppv, typeof(IPropertyDescriptionList));
        list.GetCount(out var count);
        for (uint i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            list.GetAt(i, typeof(IPropertyDescription).GUID, out var obj);
            var pd = (IPropertyDescription)obj;

            pd.GetPropertyKey(out var pk);
            Console.WriteLine($"Property Key   : {pk.fmtid:B} {pk.pid}");

            pd.GetCanonicalName(out var cname);
            Console.WriteLine($"Canonical Name : {cname}");
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem((nint)cname.Value);
            try
            {
                pd.GetDisplayName(out var dname);
                Console.WriteLine($"Display Name   : {dname}");
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem((nint)dname.Value);
            }
            catch { } // not all properties have a display name
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

