# .Net WPF TaskDialog in x64 Application

Tags: .net, wpf, windows

I am writing a WPF application and I want to show a Windows task dialog in it. I have used a home grown .Net wrapper around the Windows `TaskDialogIndirect` P/Invoke function,  and I used the OOkii dialogs NuGet package, but both fail as soon as the application is running as a 64 bit process.
I need "AnyCPU", because my code is a MS Office Add-in, and it should be able to run in 32 Bit as well as 64 Bit MS Outlook.

I want to avoid to roll my own task dialog as a WPF window, so my question:
Is there a .Net library/control suite that offers Windows Task Dialog functionality and also supports 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the NET wrapper Microsoft provided in the WindowsAPICodePack library.

This is how you can get hold of that "retired" library:

- [Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it)

See here for usage:

- https://www.developerfusion.com/article/71793/windows-7-task-dialogs/

Or you could use a library that's reimplemented most of the TaskDialog API in C#:

- https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/146
- https://github.com/kpreisser/TaskDialog

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot - Something like the API Code Pack would never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Contemporary answer: Add

```
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

to the `PropertyGroup` in your `.csproj` file and you can use all these standard dialogs directly. No, this is not an ugly hack, it seems to be the supported and recommended way...

This is where adding `TaskDialog` to .NET was discussed, with many samples: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/146

Answer (score 0):

[Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf) works fine for me in 64-bit -- and does a great job overall for task dialogs. When you say

> fail as soon as the application is running as a 64 bit process

perhaps you are referring to the [note](https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf#net-core-31--net-5-pre-requisites-before-ookiidialogswpf-v310) in their readme, which sounds like it has been fixed since they released Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf v3.1.0?