# Rich .NET Selection Dialog

Tags: .net, vb.net, dialog, modal-dialog

I've seen numerous applications with 'Rich' selection dialogues like selection dialogues in "Paint.Net" or the Windows Wizards (See Image Below). I'm looking for an alternative of a selection dialog rather using a `MessageBox` in .NET. I've search online for a long time but haven't found a definite name for these dialogues or `MessageBox` controls...

I want to make an application that uses these types of dialogues, but I don't know how to generate them unless designing them in a form manually. Is there already a way to generate these messages or do I have to design them myself?

[image: Rich Selection Dialog 1]
[image: Another Rich Selection Dialog]

Comment: I've never used it myself but I believe that what you need is what's being discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it).

Comment: The question I linked to in my previous comment is asking where the Windows API Code Pack has gone and people are discussing unofficial means to get it but my very brief research seems to suggest that it has been officially superseded by the [Windows 10 WinRT API Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This selection dialog is called the `TaskDialog` in `.NET`.
You can acquire this by importing the `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs` package from `NuGet` package manager.

A rich selection dialog can be created like this:

```
Dim dialog as new TaskDialog
dialog.text = "Title of Dialog"
dialog.caption = "Caption of Dialog"
dialog.show()
```

Additional buttons/choices can be added by consulting the `TaskDialog`'s [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.taskdialog?view=net-5.0).