# How does one detect if Windows Game Bar is active in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows-10, windows-api-code-pack

I'm trying to detect if the windows game bar is open and redirecting input as described on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160629-00/?p=93775
But in Vb.Net or C# Winforms Framework 4.7

After giving up on ChadGPT garbage suggestions i ran the c++ code through a converter and ended up with this.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.GamingServices;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    class YourClass
    {
        static GamingServices.GameBarStatics gameBarStatics;
        static bool isVisible;
        static bool isInputRedirected;
        static EventRegistrationToken tokenVisibility;
        static EventRegistrationToken tokenInput;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            gameBarStatics = GamingServices.GameBarStatics.GetDefault();
            isVisible = gameBarStatics.IsVisible;
            isInputRedirected = gameBarStatics.IsInputRedirected;
            tokenVisibility = gameBarStatics.VisibilityChanged += GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged;
            tokenInput = gameBarStatics.InputRedirected += GameBarStatics_InputRedirected;

            // Rest of your code...
        }

        static void GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged(object sender, object e)
        {
            // Handle visibility changed event...
        }

        static void GameBarStatics_InputRedirected(object sender, object e)
        {
            // Handle input redirected event...
        }
    }
}
```

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.GamingServices

Class GameBar
    Shared gameBarStatics As GamingServices.GameBarStatics
    Shared isVisible As Boolean
    Shared isInputRedirected As Boolean
    Shared tokenVisibility As EventRegistrationToken
    Shared tokenInput As EventRegistrationToken

    Public Sub New()
        gameBarStatics = GamingServices.GameBarStatics.GetDefault()
        isVisible = gameBarStatics.IsVisible
        isInputRedirected = gameBarStatics.IsInputRedirected
        tokenVisibility = AddressOf GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged
        AddHandler gameBarStatics.VisibilityChanged, AddressOf GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged
        tokenInput = AddressOf GameBarStatics_InputRedirected
        AddHandler gameBarStatics.InputRedirected, AddressOf GameBarStatics_InputRedirected
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Object)
        Debug.Print("GameBarStatics_VisibilityChanged")
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub GameBarStatics_InputRedirected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Object)
        Debug.Print("GameBarStatics_InputRedirected")
    End Sub
End Class
```

However it seems I can't find the correct NuGet package to install that exposes `GamingServices`

Note the C# code is raw and I'm not proficient enough in it to see if it has errors, I tinkered with the translated VB.Net code as it wasn't perfect but unfortunately I can't test if what I changed even works.

Comment: There is no NuGet package named "GamingServices"...

Comment: Does [Windows API Code Pack: Where is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it) help?

Comment: That API is from [Windows.Gaming.UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.ui?view=winrt-22621). You need XML Islands in .NET Framework. Better target .NET 7+ (not sure whether a CoreDispatcher is used there. In case it is, you cannot include that assembly)

Comment: @Jimi that looks like the right namespace, however it seems my project needs to be rewritten to be UWP. I'm not sure if my existing code won't break if i do that.
I'm looking into this XAML Islands thing.

Comment: [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance) -> `Earlier versions of .NET: Install the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts NuGet package`. But, do you actually need to use an *earlier versions of .NET*?

Comment: @Jimi It took a while but thanks to you i got there in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Tools/Options...` and under `NuGet Package Manager/General` set `Default package management format:` to `PackageReference`

While installing the `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts` NuGet Package click on `Configure` and add `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract` as a `Packet Source Mapping`

You can now reference `Windows.Gaming.UI.GameBar` in your code.

```
Private gbSupported As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim osVer As Version = Environment.OSVersion.Version
    If osVer.Major >= 10 AndAlso osVer.Build >= 10586 Then
        gbSupported = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: Uncomment the following line in `app.manifest` to get `Environment.OSVersion.Version` to report the right numbers.

```
<!-- Windows 10 -->
<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
```

Elsewhere in your code use

```
If gbSupported AndAlso Windows.Gaming.UI.GameBar.IsInputRedirected Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

I resorted to stuffing this into a Timer as i couldn't get the `Windows.Gaming.UI.GameBar.IsInputRedirectedChanged` event to work reliably.